# Provectus Kafka UI Unable to Load Topic Details

Tags: apache-kafka, timeoutexception

I deployed a kafka-UI container in a server and tried to connect with the kafka cluster using the below command.

`docker run -p 8080:8080 --name kafka-ui -e KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local -e KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=XX.XX.XX.XX:9093 -d provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest`

Kafka UI is able to load broker details in the web console, but it cannot load the "topic" and "consumer" details.

[image]

[image]

I can see the below error in the container logs.

```
2023-05-16 14:36:44,326 INFO  [kafka-admin-client-thread | kafka-ui-admin-1684244881-1] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=kafka-ui-admin-1684244881-1] Disconnecting from node 261 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 32528 ms.
2023-05-16 14:36:44,846 DEBUG [parallel-33] c.p.k.u.s.ClustersStatisticsScheduler: Metrics updated for cluster: local
2023-05-16 14:36:44,848 DEBUG [parallel-34] c.p.k.u.s.ClustersStatisticsScheduler: Start getting metrics for kafkaCluster: local
2023-05-16 14:36:49,053 ERROR [parallel-35] o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler: [b09cf81d-30]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/api/clusters/local/topics?page=1&perPage=25&showInternal=false"
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: listOffsets on broker 261
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.provectus.kafka.ui.controller.TopicsController#getTopics(String, Integer, Integer, Boolean, String, TopicColumnsToSortDTO, SortOrderDTO, ServerWebExchange) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ com.provectus.kafka.ui.config.ReadOnlyModeFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/clusters/local/topics?page=1&perPage=25&showInternal=false" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

When I tried the kafka topic list command manually with the same bootstrap endpoint used in the above command, it give all the topics. This confirms that the kafka cluster is running without any issues.

I tried increasing the container resources using KAFKA_UI_JVM_OPTS="-Xmx1g -Dserver.servlet.session.timeout=600". But it still didn't resolve the issue.

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your cluster require authentication, maybe?